Can't "finite" be removed from the definition of a root system?
In every definition of finite root systems I could find (reduced or not-necessarily-reduced), the root system is always assumed to be finite in the definition. It's a very minor point, but isn't this finiteness derivable from the other axioms?
From just the requirement that the root system is a subset of a positive-definite
finite-dimensional inner-product space (as a Euclidean vector space is) and the
condition that $\frac{2\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle}{\langle \beta,\beta \rangle}\in \mathbb{Z}$ for all roots, we can derive that:

The only possible multiples of a root $\alpha$ are $\alpha,-\alpha,2\alpha,-2\alpha,
\frac{1}{2}\alpha,\frac{-1}{2}\alpha$.
The angle between any two roots that are not multiples is at least $\frac{\pi}{12}$ (as $4\cos^2(\theta_{\alpha,\beta})=\frac{2\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle}{\langle \beta,\beta \rangle}\frac{2\langle \beta,\alpha\rangle}{\langle \alpha,\alpha \rangle}\in \mathbb{Z}$, where $\cos(\theta_{\alpha,\beta})$ is the angle between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

From which finiteness is immediate. I was surprised that I couldn't find any reference that made a note of this, given how fundamental a concept finite root systems are, so I think either I've made a mistake in my analysis, missed some reference where this is established, or this is just not considered important to waste time on by any author who wrote on the subject. Which is it?

In the definition of a root system I'm familiar with (e.g. the one on Wikipedia) the only possible multiples of a root $\alpha$ are $\alpha, - \alpha$. Then the observation about angles finishes it (I think this does require a small argument but it's not so bad). We can get infinite root systems by dropping the requirement that the inner product be positive-definite; these things occur in the theory of Kac-Moody algebras and Coxeter groups.

I think this is not considered particularly noteworthy because in the main application of root systems, namely the classification of finite-dimensional simple complex Lie algebras, it's already clear that every root system that occurs is finite. But I'm not sure.

On a related note, for the (infinite) affine root systems, if one drops the discreteness condition, it seems that the associated reflection group still has all hyperplanes parallel to a single (finite) set of hyperplanes that pass through a common point, corresponding to a crystallographic finite reflection group. One could probably turn this into a pseudo-affine Lie algebra (made-up terminology) by allowing the powers of t to be an arbitrary subring of the integers, or something.
